# Matlab: Error in integral function

Tags: matlab, integral-equations

I want to compute an integral with the following code written in Matlab.

```
function f = LO_scheme2a(r,kk)
% Run the Prog by :  q = integral(@(r)LO_scheme2a(r,kk), 0, inf)

%% System parameters 
lambda_m= 10^(-2);
lambda_f= kk.*lambda_m; %can be changed based on scenario
mu= 10^-4; %user density (find the proper user density or scenario based) 
Pdbm_m=43;
P_m=10.^(Pdbm_m./10);
Pdbm_f=20;
P_f=10.^(Pdbm_f./10);
gammadBm_m=0;
gamma_m=10.^(gammadBm_m./10);
gammadBm_f=0;
gamma_f=10.^(gammadBm_f./10);
alpha=4;
k=(P_f/P_m)^(1/alpha);% choose proper value
%k=.4
%% Busy Burst parameters 

Pdbm_req=0; % the optimum one should be calculated
P_req=10.^(Pdbm_req./10);
gammadBm_0=-40;
gamma_0=10.^(gammadBm_0./10);
%%
%% scheme 2
P_t=P_f;
C0=1; %By changing C_0 you can investigate the performance of system 
Theta_0=C0.* P_f;
%%
D1=(P_req./gamma_0).^(1./alpha);
D2=(Theta_0./gamma_0./P_t).^(1./alpha).*r;
D=D2;
lambda_fnew=lambda_f.*exp(-pi.*mu.*D.^2);
%%
PM_u=lambda_m./(lambda_m+k.^2.*lambda_fnew);
PF_u=lambda_fnew.*k.^2./(lambda_m+k.^2.*lambda_fnew);
%%
fm_M=2.*pi.*r.*(lambda_m+k.^2.*lambda_fnew).*exp(-pi.*r.^2.*(lambda_m+k.^2.*lambda_fnew));
ff_F=2.*pi.*r.*(lambda_m./k.^2+lambda_fnew).*exp(-pi.*r.^2.*(lambda_m./k.^2+lambda_fnew));
%%
%% Interference from MBSs to MU an FU
A_i= 1;
S_i=gamma_m .*r.^alpha;
LIm_m=exp(-pi.*lambda_m.*(A_i.*r).^2.*rho1(gamma_m,alpha));
%LIm_m=exp(-pi.*lambda_m.*(A_i.*r).^2.*rho0(S_i./(A_i.*r).^alpha,alpha));
A_i= 1./k;
S_i=gamma_f .*r.^alpha *P_m/P_f;
LIf_m=exp(-pi.*lambda_m.*(A_i.*r).^2.*rho1(gamma_f.*P_m.*k.^alpha./P_f,alpha));
%LIf_m=exp(-pi.*lambda_m.*(A_i.*r).^2.*rho0(S_i./(A_i.*r).^alpha,alpha));

%%
max_x= 10^5;
%% Expectation over h in lemmma 3 :  Interference from FAPs to MU an FU
S_i=gamma_f .*r.^alpha .*P_f./P_m;
z=(P_req/gamma_0).^(1/alpha);
%MIm_f=(exp(-h).*exp(-mu.*pi.*z^2.*h.^(2./alpha))).*((-((z.^2).*h^(2/alpha)).*(1-exp(-S_i.*z.^(-alpha))))+(S_i.*h).^(2./alpha).*real(gammainc(1-(2./alpha),S_i.*z.^(-alpha))));
for idx = 1:numel(r)
    MIm_f(idx)=  integral(@(h)exp(-h).*((exp(-mu.*pi.*z^2.*h.^(2./alpha))).*((-((z.^2).*h.^(2./alpha)).*(1-exp(-S_i.*z.^(-alpha))))+(S_i.*h).^(2./alpha).*real(gammainc(1-(2./alpha),S_i.*z.^(-alpha))))),0,max_x);
end
% % 
S_i=gamma_f .*r.^alpha ;
z=(P_req./gamma_0).^(1/alpha);

for idx = 1:numel(r)
    MIf_f(idx)=  integral(@(h)(exp(-h).*exp(-mu.*pi.*z^2.*h.^(2./alpha))).*((-((z.^2).*h.^(2./alpha)).*(1-exp(-S_i.*z.^(-alpha))))+(S_i.*h).^(2./alpha).*real(gammainc(1-(2./alpha),S_i.*z.^(-alpha)))),0,max_x);
end
%%

f=PM_u.*LIm_m.*exp(-2.*pi.*lambda_f.*MIm_f).*fm_M+PF_u.*LIf_m.*exp(-2.*pi.*lambda_f.*MIf_f).*ff_F;
```

where

```
function [ f_rho ] = rho1( x,alpha)
f_rho=x.^(2./alpha).*(pi./2-atan(x.^(-2./alpha)));
end
```

I can run it for various values of kk, but for some kk it gives me an error. For example, when kk=10, I can run this program with the command

```
 q = integral(@(r)LO_scheme2a(r,kk), 0, inf)
```

but for kk=100, it gives me an error.

> (Error using  .* Matrix dimensions must agree.)

Would you please help me to find the source of this error?

Comment: Your code isn't runnable. It depends on the function `rho1`. Also complete error messages including line numbers are much more helpful. Have you tried [debugging](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/debugging-code.html)? Finally, [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab) would probably be a more appropriate place for this question.

Comment: Thanks, I add rho1 function to my question. I debug it but I couldn't find the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `q = integral(@(r)LO_scheme2a(r,kk), 0, inf)`, the `integral function chooses`r`, which is a vector that discretizes the integration bounds. The [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html) states:

> For scalar-valued problems, the function y = fun(x) must accept a vector argument, x, and return a vector result, y. This generally means that fun must use array operators instead of matrix operators. For example, use .* (times) rather than * (mimes).

Your error(s) occur where you call `integral` again from within your code. At this point `r` is a vector (a vector that can change size) and you don't have a scalar-valued problem. You have tried to deal with this with your two `for` loops. However, the right hand sides of both loops don't depend on your index variable `idx`, i.e., `r(idx)`.

However, you don't even need `for` loops as the documentation above continues:

> If you set the 'ArrayValued' option to true, fun must accept a scalar and return an array of fixed size.

Thus, using the [`'ArrayValued'`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html#inputarg_ArrayValued) option, your `for` loops can be replaced with:

```
...
fun = @(h,S_i,z)exp(-h).*exp(-mu*pi*z^2*h.^(2/alpha)) ...
                       .*(-z^2*h.^(2/alpha).*(1-exp(-S_i*z^-alpha)) ...
                       +(S_i.*h).^(2/alpha).*real(gammainc(1-2/alpha,S_i*z^-alpha)));
MIm_f = integral(@(h)fun(h,S_i,z),0,max_x,'ArrayValued',true);

S_i = gamma_f.*r.^alpha ;
z = (P_req./gamma_0).^(1/alpha);

MIf_f = integral(@(h)fun(h,S_i,z),0,max_x,'ArrayValued',true);
...
```

I've also cleaned up your anonymous function and added two extra parameters so you can re-use it ([see here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/passing-extra-parameters.html#brhkghv-9)).